# Sum of series $a^{i^2}$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, power-series, closed-form-expressions

Is there any closed form known for the expression $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a^{i^2}$ where $|a|<1$? Thanks!

Comment: No. But look up "theta functions".

Comment: Oh thanks. I forgot to correct the title...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling your function $f(a),$ it is clear that $f(a)^{4} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r_{4}(n) a^{n},$ where $r_{4}(n)$ is the number of ways to express $n$ as a sum of four integer squares, as proved by Jacobi, who also gave an explicit description of $r_{4}(n)$ in terms of the divisors of $n.$ I that sense ( and really regarding $f(a)$ as a formal power series in $a,$ which is a slight abuse), $f(a)$ is the fourth root of a "known" function.

Comment: Is $r_4(n)$ more "known" than $a^{n^2}$?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay : I know what you mean, but the spirit of the question seems to be to describe the given series in terms of something "more familiar"

Comment: Actually, Jacobi's $r_4(n)$ refers to squares of integers, not positive integers, so it's $(1+2f(a))^4=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r_4(n)a^n$. That's an essentially different problem. As Sergei Points out, $1+2f(a)$ is a theta function, and Jacobi's work on 2, 4, 6 and 8 squares is based on exploiting this fact.

Comment: @HjalmarRosengren : OK, thanks,  so $1+2f(a)$ is the 4-th root of a "known" function.

Comment: I you insist. But to me that is like saying $\cos(z)$ is the fourth root of the known function $\cos^4(z)$. Theta functions are quite fundamental and appear in lots of contexts apart from sums of four squares.

Comment: I understand that point, as I understand the link between Jacobi's work and theta functions.

Answer (score 15):

This sum equals exactly to: 
$$ \frac{1}{2}\left(\theta_3 (0,a) -1 \right),$$
and $\theta_3$ is the Jacobi $\theta$ - function.